# Pictures place problem

Tags: floats

I use the IEEE template, and I hope to place two pictures side by side. But if I use the 'minipage', it will change the two column of the IEEE template.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!tp]
\begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1in]{Figure1.pdf}
\caption{This is Figure 1}
\label{figure 1}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1in]{Figure2.pdf}
\caption{This is Figure 2}
\label{figure 2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I'm sure it's not because the pictures too wide. I have try to change the width, but it's no use.

**The result is:**
[image]

**But, I hope the result is like this:**
[image]

How to achieve this result? And how to change the code?

Thank you!

Comment: `minipage` doesn't do that, the `figure*` environment does. Use `figure` (without the `*`).

Comment: And use `\columnwidth` instead `\textwidth` for the minipages: `\begin{minipage}{.49\columnwidth}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you! After I removing the *, it is not placed side by side anymore. Finally, I change the set from \textwidth to \columnwidth, and it works. thank you all the same!

Comment: @WYSIWYG  I think they are different questions. Thank you all the same!

Comment: @esdd  Thank you! I do as what you said. It works!